# Darle borde a li con css

Tags: css, css3, hover

tengo este estilo que obtuve de la pagina

https://cybmeta.com/formas-basicas-con-css-triangulos-circulos-trapecios-rectangulos-cuadrados

```
.circulo {
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         -moz-border-radius: 50%;
         -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
         border-radius: 50%;
         background: #5cb85c;
    }
```

sin que deje de ser circulo, quiero darle un borde cuando le de click y que cuando sea hover se agrande un poco

y con esto lo aumento en el hover

```
.circle ul li a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);transform:scale(1.3);
    cursor:pointer; 
    cursor: hand;
}
```

[image: Menu]

Como pueden ver en el centro en la parte de abajo esta el "circulo" y tiene centro blanco y borde rosado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que se agrande con el hover puedes usar lo que has hecho modificar las propiedades de `width` y `height` dentro del css que has hecho.

Por otra parte, para hacer el borde cuando hagas click puedes hacerlo de varias formas pero en todas utilizas javaScript.

Un ejemplo es haciendo una clase de css sólo para ese borde:

```
.borde {
border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Y añadiéndola al círculo al hacer click mediante un js:

```
document.querySelector(".circle").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector(".circle").addClass("borde");
}
```

Otra solución sería añdirle directamente la propiedad del borde mediante js:

```
document.querySelector(".circle").style.border= "solid 1px #000";
```

Comment: Voy a ensayar poniéndoselo desde el principio, para que aparezca con el borde desde que carga,  porque me toca crear todo el evento del click,

Comment: He añadido el evento click en la respuesta, se me había pasado, por si quieres verlo. Si prefieres que aparezca siempre, solo debes añadir el estilo del borde en el primer css que tienes, aunque sea circular se comporta como un cuadrado en cuanto a propiedades de css.

Comment: tengo una duda, ya lo hace, pero si quiero aumentar el tamaño del borde me cubre la imagen central , añadiré a la pregunta a que debo llegar

Comment: Ya lo añadí, en esa imagen ven como debe quedarse viendo, la cosa es que si aumento el tamaño del borde me cubre el original

Comment: Sobre la sombra, como evito que se vea difuminada? use esta: `box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px 25px #EA0B8C;`

Comment: Para que el borde no se coma lo que es el círculo en sí, añádele a su css `box-sizing: content-box`. En cuanto a la sombra, el primer número es la posición a la derecha, el segundo hacia abajo, el tercero es lo que se difumina y el cuarto el tamaño o distancia. Si no quieres que esté difuminado tienes que poner a 0 el tercer número, el que tienes en 27 pero, para que se vea, tendrás que cambiar el primero o segundo o ambos, sino estará totalmente detrás y no se verá nada.